# how to refer all the records in dataview after click on one common button. in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have dataview List of some record. In a list I am displaying Item_name, item_no, Item_desc and a single number field. There is one toolbar at top of the list which is having a button for adding a record to the store. The user will see the record in list and then he will add quantity of the items that he is interested in the number field.

Then, after clicking on the "add to store" button, I want to add all that record to the store which user is interested (means record that are having some value in the number field).

How can I specify an ID for each number field separately? I am declaring the number field only once in the data component of the dataview list. Right now I have given an id to the number field, but it takes the reference of the number field of the last record in the dataview list. I want it to take the reference of all number fields and records.

Also, after click of common Add to store button, how can I refer each record against each number field?

Answer (score 0):

If the field is repeated multiple times in DOM you should not us ID, instead you can try using 'itemId' or use `class` attribute so that you can use component query to fetch list of those fields e.g.

```
// Returns all instances of the component with an
// itemId of "whitebox" that is nested at any  level  
// in the items array of mycontainer that have a cls 
// property with a value of "white"
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("mycontainer #whitebox[cls=white]");
```